# python read files from wsgi input

Tags: python, wsgi

So, I'm playing around by building WSGI app, I'm trying to read files from post request but I keep getting

```
b'------WebKitFormBoundaryEpoVZBBn8QAZveiC\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_data"\r\n\r\ntext data\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryEpoVZBBn8QAZveiC--\r\n'
```

so how can I parse that to get a dict with key as the name and value as the file or that data sent from post request

```
class Server:
    routes = {}
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        _b = environ['wsgi.input']
        print(_b.read())
        start_response("200 OK", [('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')])
        return [bytes(render_template('index.html', environ), encoding='utf-8')]

app = Server()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app, port=5000)
```

that's the client script code

```
<script>
    let filer = document.getElementById('files')
    const form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.onsubmit = e => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        for (let index = 0; index < filer.files.length.length; index++) {
            const element = filer.files[index];
            formData.append('files', element)
        }

        formData.append('_data', "text data")

        axios.post("http://localhost:5000/message/create/", formData, {
            Headers : {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'}
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by

```
d = cgi.FieldStorage(environ=environ, fp=_b, keep_blank_values=True)
```

to access files, `d['files']`
to access data, `d.getvalue("_data")`